# MYSQL - Should I use multiple subtables or one subtable for data descriptors?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a table to store data from various government reports. An example row in the table would be:

Values_table

```
Date           Location     Report       Attribute    Value
'2014-09-29'   'U.S.'       'LM_HG201'   'Price'      210
```

Obviously I do not want to save strings for all of these columns, so I will be making subtables with ids to use instead. In order to balance table speed and ease of use, would it be better to make multiple subtables like:

Location_table

```
ID     Location
1      'U.S' 
2      'World'
```

Report_table

```
ID     Report
1      'LM_HG201'
```

Attribute_table

```
ID     Attribute
1      'Price'
```

Where my query of the values table is something like:

```
SELECT value FROM Values_table 
  WHERE location = (SELECT id FROM locations_table WHERE location = 'U.S') 
  AND attribute = (SELECT id FROM attributes_table WHERE attribute = 'price')
```

Or would it be better to use a single descriptors subtable, like this:

Descriptors_table

```
ID      Location       Report       Attribute
1       'U.S.'         'LM_HG201'   'Price'
```

Where my query of the values table would be:

```
SELECT value FROM values_table
  WHERE descriptor_id IN (SELECT id FROM descriptors_table 
  WHERE location = 'U.S.' AND report = 'LM_HG201' AND attribute = 'Price')
```

In my mind the second approach seems better but I've never seen it done this way. Any thoughts on which is worse/better?

Comment: I would have seeing "_table" appended to the name of every relation.  They ought to be singular nouns without the Hungarian appendage.  I'd name those table Value, Location, Attribute (or perhaps other, more descriptive, alternatives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization rules and business requirements ought to drive your design.

If Location is repeated for several reports, it might make sense to normalize it.

I would not split out Price, because that would appear to be unique to a report.  Repetitions down to the penny would be serendipity.

You should learn [how to design relational models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and what normalization rules are.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT V.Value
FROM Values_table V 
INNER JOIN locations_table   L  ON  L.id = V.location  
INNER JOIN attributes_table  A  ON  A.Id = V.attribute 
INNER JOIN descriptors_table D  ON  D.id = V.descriptor_id 
WHERE L.location = 'U.S'
 AND  A.attribute = 'price'
 AND  D.report = 'LM_HG201'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema should be
Id Location Report Price
and 210 should be a value under 'Price' in the corresponding row.
If you have different attributes for different types of reports, use subtables and/or subtypes. Most systems implement these (but not MySQL).